# Function returning empty list instead of List<String>

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function which accepts a `List<File>` and return List of Urls`(List<String>)` by uploading the file to the firebase storage.

the file is uploading to the storage and the URL is generating for individual uploads(checked using print statement).

but when I am trying to add this URL into a list and return the list, the function is always returning an empty list.
this is my function:

```
  Future<List<String>> uploadImages(List<File> imageFiles) async {
    List<String> imageUrlList = [];
    imageFiles.forEach((File imageFile) async {
      final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref('/tempImages')
          .child('${DateTime.now().toString()}image.jpg');
      await ref.putFile(imageFile);
      final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      print(url);
      imageUrlList.insert(0, url);
    });
    print(imageUrlList);
    return imageUrlList;
  }
```

the second print statement is not even printing to the debug console.
can someone help me out here?

Comment: isnt it `list.add()`?

Comment: @sittsering `list.add(...)` would add at the end, `list.insert(0, ...)` adds to the front.

Comment: @sittsering `list.add()` is not the issue. The async/await behaviour is not handled

Comment: okay, understood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `forEach` won't work as you think actually. The second print statement is reached before the forEach is completed it's operation.

You have to use traditional `for` loops to make things work. Like below.

```
Future<List<String>> uploadImages(List<File> imageFiles) async {
    List<String> imageUrlList = [];
    for(var i=0; i<imageFiles.length; i++) {
        var imageFile = imageFiles[i];
        final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref('/tempImages')
        .child('${DateTime.now().toString()}image.jpg');
       await ref.putFile(imageFile);
       final url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
       imageUrlList.insert(0, url);
    }
    print(imageUrlList);
    return imageUrlList;
  }
```

The reason why it isn't working on forEach is, the statement is just a single function call. The function call on an array method. So interpreter calls it and moves to next line, which is print, and return. So at this time, those image files were not uploaded yet.